# How to display 2 set of separate images in a collection view in ios based on Recently added and Most popular button clicked

Tags: swift

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lj9BK.png)

Above is the image. Based on button click, the set of images is shown and scroll vertically using collection view.

Comment: Are you beginner in swift? Did you worked on CollectionView?

Comment: just change array of popular and recently added item on button change n pass it to collection view